# How to change data with Javascript as DataTables displays it into a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am very new to Javascript, I am working to extend pieces of code implemented by third parts and I have to slightly change some data before it is displayed into a html table via [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

In particular, data comes from the columns "nested field" and "subfields" of a Postgres database table, declared as:

```
CREATE TABLE testing_nested_field_blacklist (
    nested_field    varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    subfields       varchar(100)[] NOT NULL
);
```

The html table filled up with data looks like this:

[image]

Data coming from column "subfields" is displayed into the table as a string of words separated by commas (`,`), but what I want instead is words to be separated by comma and one space (`,` ) , like this:

[image]

In order to get this, I am thinking about

1. building a function that, given a string as input, substitutes
   commas with comma-and-space and returns it as output
2. put the function in a for cycle that applyes the substitution to element of column "subfields"
   for each row of the table, and I would put this function at the end of the script that loads
   the data into the table. So that it gets triggered also when "refresh", "add", "edit" and
   "delete" functions are triggered.

However, I don't know how to get and change the data.
Can anybody point me the right direction to do this?

This is the javascript piece of code that displays the data into the html template:

```
var NestedFieldTable;
var nested_field_to_remove = {};
var nested_field;

    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        // NESTED FIELD
        NestedFieldTable = $('#NestedFieldTable').DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "processing":true,
            "ajax":  {
                "url": '/getNestedFields/',
                "type":"POST",
                "dataSrc": "nested_field"
            },
            "columns": columns_nested_field,
            "columnDefs": [
                {"targets": -1, "data": null, "defaultContent": "<i class='fas fa-edit' aria-hidden='true' id='modifyRow' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalEditNestedField' title='click to edit nested field or blacklist'></i><i style='margin-left:15px;' class='fas fa-trash' aria-hidden='true' id='deleteRow' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalDeleteNestedField'  title='Click to delete nested field and blacklist'></i>", "width": "75px"},
            ],
            "dom":  "<'row'<'col-md-6 toolbar_nestedfield'><'col-md-6'fBl>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-md-6'><'col-md-6'>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-12'pi>>",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    autoClose: true,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: '<i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print',
                            extend: 'print',
                            messageTop: 'Table of subfields and nested field .',
                            footer: false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: '<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'Refresh table',
                    action: function ( e, dt) {
                        dt.ajax.reload();
                        set_alert_message({"title":"Refresh", "detail":"Table successfully refreshed"}, "success");
                    }
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "searchPlaceholder": "Search",
                "search": "<div class='form-group'><div class='input-group'><div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text'><i class='fas fa-search fa-fw'></i></span></div>_INPUT_</div></div>",
                "lengthMenu": "<div class='form-group'><div class='input-group'><div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text'><i class='fas fa-list-ul fa-fw'></i></span></div>_MENU_</div></div>",
                "oPaginate": {
                    sNext: '<span class="pagination-default">&#x276f;</span>',
                    sPrevious: '<span class="pagination-default">&#x276e;</span>'
                }
            }
        });
        $(".toolbar_nestedfield").html('<button type="button" class="dt-button" title="click to add new nested field and blacklist" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAddNestedField"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>');
```

This is the javascript piece of code that defines the columns of the tabel, and it is necessary to make DataTables work:

```
var columns_nested_field = [
    { "title":"Nested field", data: "nested_field"},
    { "title":"Subfields blacklist", data: "subfields"},
    { "title":"Edit", "orderable": false, "className": 'icon_dt_style'}
];
```

and this is the html template:

```
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <ol class="breadcrumb shadow-lg">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="/4testing/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Nested fields and subfields blacklists</li>
    </ol>

    <!-- alert messages -->
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong id="alert-success-title"></strong> <div id="alert-success-detail"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong id="alert-danger-title"></strong> <div id="alert-danger-detail"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- TABELLA NESTED FIELDS -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><i class="fas fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nested fields and subfields blacklists</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="NestedFieldTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Have a look at the [render method](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) of the column definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

As suggested in the comments by @Lapskaus, data displayed by DataTables can be manipulated by using the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) method.

In my case I had to apply the same change to all elements of an array (having each cell of column `subfields` containing an array), so I used the [**Array-access** render method](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Array-access).

I added the element key-value `render: "[my-separator]"` to object

```
{ "title":"Subfields blacklist", data: "subfields"}
```

of variable `columns_nested_field`, that corresponds to the column whose data I want to manipulate (`"render": "[my-separator]"` works as well).

And since I want `,`  as separator, I turned my variable

```
var columns_nested_field = [
    { "title":"Nested field", data: "nested_field"},
    { "title":"Subfields blacklist", data: "subfields"},
    { "title":"Edit", "orderable": false, "className": 'icon_dt_style'}
];
```

into

```
var columns_nested_field = [
    { "title":"Nested field", data: "nested_field"},
    { "title":"Subfields blacklist", data: "subfields", render: "[, ]"}, // <-- added the render key
    { "title":"Edit", "orderable": false, "className": 'icon_dt_style'}
];
```

so that I get

[image]